# How to edit a Content Editor Webpart located in a custom ASPX?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom aspx page on which I have added a Content Editor WP through SharePoint Designer. On the designer I'm (of course) able to edit the webpart and add it some content, but I would like users of the website to be able to modify the content of the webpart by clicking the usual "Edit Page" on the aspx, which is not available.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try appending ?toolpaneview=2 to the end of the page url.

This should bring the page up in editing mode, providing you have the right permissions.

/**** Edit ****/

Sorry scrap that you will need to give them permissions to edit the page I believe, at that point they should be able to see the site actions dropdown to select edit themselves.

Thanks
Gary

Comment: I have tried to add the toolpaneview attribute, but it didn't work. as you say, I probably don't have the rights but for the moment I have no way to get them... thanks anyway !